# Route components from json

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to generate my routes in this way :

Error message : "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {contents})".

```
class App extends Component {
    menu(){
        return {
            menu:[
                {id:1, text:"Dashboard", component: <Dashboard/>},
                {id:2, text:"Users", component: <Users/>},
            ]
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <Router data={this.menu()}/>
            </HashRouter>
      );
    }
};


class Router extends Component {
    render() {
        let menu = this.props.data.menu,
        contents = menu.map((elem, i) =>{
            return <Route exact
                path={"/" +elem.text.toLowerCase()}
                component={elem.component}/> //How to call the component here ?
        }, this);
        console.log(contents);
        return(
            {contents} //Error
            //<Route exact path={"/" +elem.text.toLowerCase()} render={Dashboard}/> // Works
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: Seens like you need to put your `{contents`} between `div` tags

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you explain why fastly ?

Comment: I put once more example to you in my explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a example for you using `codesanbox.io` https://codesandbox.io/s/6l9r1qwkzk

Seems like that `props.menu.data` don't receive `component` property.

```
const Router = ({ data }) => JSON.stringify(data);
```

and the output as below:

```
{"menu":[{"id":1,"text":"Dashboard"},{"id":2,"text":"Users"}]}
```

> #### Pay attention

You can't instantiate a component in your json data like this:

```
{ id: 2, text: "Users", component: <Users /> }
```

The error for that is `Converting circular structure to JSON`

#### * Edit 1 - Added my localhost test

Strangely the `codesandbox.io` does not debug the component as a function, so I've re-built it on my local machine

[image]

### * Edit 2 - Try to use `React adopt`

Compose render props components link a pro

[image]

#### Reference:

- [github.com - pedronauck/react-adopt](https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt)

I hope I've been useful! :)

Comment: Very interesting ! And I learnt a new tool that is codesandbox.
Thanks